# Redirecting users to same dynamic page in asp.net.

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, redirect

I am working on a dynamic website.

I am able to redirect users to a page using the code in `web.config`

```
add `url="~/baked-foods" mappedUrl="~/food_type.aspx?PID=1"/></pre>`
```

This works perfect for me and takes to `www.food.com/baked-foods`

Now I want to use another url like `www.food.com/baked-foods/`

It should take me to the same page of

```
www.food.com/food_type.aspx?PID=1
```

I have added one slash at the end. I want to have both urls to be redirected to the same page.

Kindly suggest me a best solution to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You just add another `<add>` child element to the `<urlMappings>` element.